# Assembly (TASM) plotting pixel through writing in memory

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86, tasm

My old code printed a line in mode 13h with `int 10h`. I tried to change it from using `int 10h` into  writing in memory but for some reason it doesn't work. I am not familiar with writing in memory so I couldn't guess what is the problem.

Here's the new code:

```
proc PrintLine
;prints a line
;1.length 
;2.colour
;3.x
;4.y
push bp
mov bp,sp
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
push si
mov cx,[bp+10];leangth
mov dx,[bp+4];y
mov al,[bp+8];colour
mov si,[bp+6];x
xor bx,bx
pl:
    push si
    push dx
    push ax
    call PrintPixel
loop pl
pop si
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
pop bp
ret 8
endp PrintLine
proc PrintPixel
;print a pixel through writing into memory
;input:
;1.x
;2.y
;3.colour
;output:
;none
push bp
mov bp,sp
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
push di
mov ax,0A000h
mov es,ax
mov ax,[bp+6];y
mov bx,[bp+8];x
mov dl,[bp+4];colour
mov cx,320
mul cx;each line is 320 pixles ax is the number of lines
add ax,bx;bx is the place on the line
mov di,ax
mov [es:di],dl
mov ax, @data  
mov ds, ax
pop di
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
pop bp
ret 6
endp PrintPixel
```

This is the old code with `int 10h`:

```
proc PrintLine
;prints a line
;1.length 
;2.colour
;3.x
;4.y
push bp
mov bp,sp
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
push si
mov cx,[bp+10];leangth
mov dx,[bp+4];y
mov al,[bp+8];colour
mov si,[bp+6];x
mov ah,0ch
xor bx,bx
pl:
    push cx
    mov cx,si
    int 10h
    inc si
    pop cx  
loop pl
pop si
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
pop bp
ret 8
endp PrintLine
```

Comment: That's a big dump of code with absolutely no whitespace or comments, so it's extremely difficult to read. I can't tell if you have code in there that sets the video mode, so I'll just ask you: what video mode are you using? That affects the layout of pixel data in memory.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am using mode 13h.

Comment: @hjsv41: You not setting mode 13h anywhere in the code you present. Are you sure it is on?

Comment: This is just a snippet from the code.The whole code is about 800 lines.I am setting it in the start of my program

    start:
    mov ax, @data  
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax,13h
    int 10h

Comment: In the `pl:` loop, I don't see how you increase the x coordinate. BTW, the main idea to have efficient code is to remove redundant operations, assembler is not fast because executing single instruction is fast (it's not, you have only few millions-billions per second, which is actually easier to exhaust than you may think), but assembly is fast because you can use all kind of shortcuts... like: es=A000 just once outside of printLine/Pixel (preserving `es` for whole drawing code). Or calculating address of first pixel of horizontal line, then doing ++address instead of full calculation per pix.

Comment: "doesn't work" => does it produce single dot? "doesn't work" is usually very bad description and may turn away people who would be potentially able to help. Also if it's like that, and all that you miss is `inc si`, then you should have figured out easily with debugger, so it looks like you don't use one, which makes programming in assembly like 100x times harder than it should be.

Comment: You know your pixel color is wiped out (always zero) after each mul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *PrintPixel* procedure has 2 important problems.

- Although you preserve a lot of registers, you also use the `ES` segment register that you don't preserve at all! Why you then re-initialize the `DS` segment register is a mystery.
- Because you calculate the video offset address using `mul cx` you've gotten a dword product in `DX:AX`, but you kept the pixel color in `DL`. This can only result in black pixels! They're there but you can't see them.

Since this question was tagged [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) you can use the versatile `imul` instruction:

```
push bp
mov  bp, sp
push ax
push bx
push ds
mov  ax, 0A000h
mov  ds, ax
mov  bx, 320      ; Bytes per line in mode 13h
imul bx, [bp+6]   ; y
add  bx, [bp+8]   ; x
mov  al, [bp+4]   ; colour
mov  [bx], al     <-- No need for any segment override prefix!
pop  ds
pop  bx
pop  ax
pop  bp
ret  6
```

See how much cleaner and shorter this has become?

---

With the shift to no longer using the BIOS *WritePixel* you should also clean-up the *PrintLine* procedure. It no longer needs e.g. the `xor bx, bx`.
Did you know you can push a memory operand directly? Doing so, you'll save a lot of instructions!

```
 push bp
 mov  bp, sp
 push cx
 mov  cx, [bp+10]       ; length
pl:
 push word ptr [bp+6]   ; x
 push word ptr [bp+4]   ; y
 push word ptr [bp+8]   ; colour
 call PrintPixel
 loop pl
 pop  cx
 pop  bp
 ret  8
```